# Can`t create C++ ConsoleApplication or C++ EmptyProject in VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, project

I try to create C++ ConsoleApplication or C++ EmptyProject in VS 2015 but this buttons not works. After clicking "create" anything happens. But it is possible to create StaticLibrary project.
Why it happens? And how to fix it?

Here link on video how it looks like:

[[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oVxC.jpg)](https://youtu.be/S1pKqfguMRM)

Comment: File -> Create new project?

Comment: The same behavior. By File->New->Project.

Comment: Did it use to work? Is is a recent install? Normatlly, even community edition should be able to create empty projects...

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, it works normally on another PC, but not here. As I found it`s problematic remove VS2015 and the most clear way to fix it is reinstall Windows.

Comment: Still the marvelous windows installs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case solution was to change language. In Tools->Options->Environment->Internationsl Settings.